# How to import file sas7bdat into R with where clause

Tags: r, import, sas, sqldf, rsqlite

I would like to import a file in .sas7bdat into R. The file is very big, so I need to import only the rows that match given criteria.

With a file .csv, the code would be

```
library(sqldf)
read.csv.sql("mtcars.csv", sql = "select * from file where carb in (1,2)" )
```

How can I do the same thing, but for a .sas7bdat file ?

I already tried with sqldf package :

```
library(sqldf)
data <- file("file.sas7bdat")
sqldf("select * from data where CONDITION1 eq 'CRITERIA1'")
```

However, it does not work and it says:

> Error in utils::read.table(value, sep = sep, header = header, skip = skip,  : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Comment: Is it impossible to import the whole thing or you just don't want too? Have you looked into the package `haven`?

Comment: I want to import only the rows that match input criteria (and, by the way, since the database is huge, I think it is also lighter to do so). I looked into `haven` but I didn't find the solution. I know how to do it in csv, but not with a file in .sas7bdat. Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: Do you have access to SAS on your machine or just have a large SAS file with no version of SAS on your computer?

Comment: I have access to SAS on my machine but I do not want to filter the dataset using SAS. I would like to do it only by using R. I know how to do it for a csv and for a connection with a SAS server. However, I do not know how to do it when I am importing a sas7bdat file.

Comment: I looked around and couldn't find a good solution to subset rows. However `haven::read_sas()` has a `cols_only` input argument that will only read in select columns. This would help with speed.  You could also look into `foreign` or `SASxport`. example using haven - 
`cnames <- colnames(mtcars)[1:5]

haven::read_sas("G:/mtcars.sas7bdat", cols_only = cnames)`